# How to solve the problem of character change that use write.xlsx() to writes data into excel document in R language?

Tags: r, openxlsx

I write a data.frame into an excel document through the function of write.xlsx. The header of the data.frame contains the characters like "95%CI", "Pr(>|W|)", etc. The data.frame is output in the r console without any problem, but when I written it into Excel file through write.xlsx(), 95% CI becomes X95.CI, and Pr(>|W|) becomes Pr...W..
How to solve this problem?
The test code is as follows:

```r
library("openxlsx")

mydata <- data.frame("95%CI" = 1,
                     "Pr(>|W|)" =2)
write.xlsx(mydata,
           "test.xlsx", 
           sheetName = "test",
           overwrite = TRUE,
           borders = "all", colWidths="auto")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this code works correctly in R console as well.

```
mydata <- data.frame("95%CI" = 1,"Pr(>|W|)" =2)
mydata

#  X95.CI Pr...W..
#1      1        2
```

You have some non-standard characters in column names (like `%`, `(`, `>` etc), if you want to keep them use `check.names = FALSE` in `data.frame` function.

```
mydata <- data.frame("95%CI" = 1,"Pr(>|W|)" =2, check.names = FALSE)
mydata

#  95%CI Pr(>|W|)
#1     1        2
```

Now when you write it to excel -

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(mydata,
           "test.xlsx", 
           sheetName = "test",
           overwrite = TRUE,
           borders = "all", colWidths="auto")
```

[image]